# mediapipe poseを用いたジェスチャー認識について

Tags: python

mediapipe poseを用いたジェスチャー認識を行いたく、下のURLでmediapipe handsを利用されているのを参考にしているのですが、想定している挙動にならず困っております。

[MediaPipeを利用して簡単なジェスチャーを推定するレシピ](https://axross-recipe.com/recipes/136)

問題となっているのは、chapter2以降の有効なランドマークが検出された場合、ランドマークを描画する過程で起きていると考えられ、サンプルコードでは指先の軌跡が描画されるのに対して、自分の書いているコードでは、手首の座標を保持するDeque内にたいてい同じ座標しか保持されておらず、軌跡が表示できていない状況です。

こちらのサイトを利用するのも始めてで、至らぬ点が多々あるかと思いますがよろしくお願いいたします。

参照したページからのサンプルコード

```
# chapter02.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from collections import deque

import cv2
import mediapipe as mp


# ランドマークの画像上の位置を算出する関数
def calc_landmark_list(image, landmarks):
    landmark_point = []
    image_width, image_height = image.shape[1], image.shape[0]

    for _, landmark in enumerate(landmarks.landmark):
        landmark_x = min(int(landmark.x * image_width), image_width - 1)
        landmark_y = min(int(landmark.y * image_height), image_height - 1)
        landmark_point.append([landmark_x, landmark_y])

    return landmark_point


# 座標履歴を描画する関数
def draw_point_history(image, point_history):
    for index, point in enumerate(point_history):
        if point[0] != 0 and point[1] != 0:
            cv2.circle(image, (point[0], point[1]), 1 + int(index / 2),
                       (255, 0, 0), 2)
    return image


# カメラキャプチャ設定
camera_no = 0
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_no)
video_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
video_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 360)

# MediaPipe Hands初期化
mp_hands = mp.solutions.hands
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

hands = mp_hands.Hands(
    max_num_hands=1,  # 最大手検出数：1
    min_detection_confidence=0.5,  # 検出信頼度閾値：0.5
    min_tracking_confidence=0.5  # トラッキング信頼度閾値：0.5
)

# 人差指のID
ID_FINGER_TIP = 8

# 人差指の指先の座標履歴を保持するための変数
history_length = 16
point_history = deque(maxlen=history_length)

while video_capture.isOpened():
    # カメラ画像取得
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    if ret is False:
        break

    # 鏡映しになるよう反転
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)

    # MediaPipeで扱う画像は、OpenCVのBGRの並びではなくRGBのため変換
    rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # 画像をリードオンリーにしてHands検出処理実施
    rgb_image.flags.writeable = False
    hands_results = hands.process(rgb_image)
    rgb_image.flags.writeable = True

    # 有効なランドマークが検出された場合、ランドマークを描画
    if hands_results.multi_hand_landmarks:
        for hand_landmarks in hands_results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(frame, hand_landmarks,
                                      mp_hands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)

            # ランドマーク座標の計算
            landmark_list = calc_landmark_list(rgb_image, hand_landmarks)
            # 人差指の指先座標を履歴に追加
            point_history.append(landmark_list[ID_FINGER_TIP])

    # ディスプレイ表示
    frame = draw_point_history(frame, point_history)
    cv2.imshow('chapter02', frame)

    # キー入力(ESC:プログラム終了)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:  # ESC
        break

# リソースの解放
video_capture.release()
hands.close()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

自分の書いているコード

```
# chapter02.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from collections import deque
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp


# ランドマークの画像上の位置を算出する関数
def calc_landmark_list(image, landmarks):
    landmark_point = []
    image_width, image_height = image.shape[1], image.shape[0]
    for _, landmark in enumerate(landmarks.landmark):
        landmark_x = min(int(landmark.x * image_width), image_width - 1)
        landmark_y = min(int(landmark.y * image_height), image_height - 1)
        landmark_point.append([landmark_x, landmark_y])
    return landmark_point


# 座標履歴を描画する関数
def draw_point_history(image, point_history):
    for index, point in enumerate(point_history):
        if point[0] != 0 and point[1] != 0:
            cv2.circle(image, (point[0], point[1]), 1 + int(index / 2),
                       (255, 0, 0), 2)
    return image


# カメラキャプチャ設定
camera_no = 0
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_no)
video_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
video_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 360)

# MediaPipe Pose初期化
mp_pose = mp.solutions.pose
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

pose = mp_pose.Pose(
    min_detection_confidence = 0.5, # 検出信頼度閾値：0.5
    min_tracking_confidence = 0.5  # トラッキング信頼度閾値：0.5 
    )

# 各代表点のID
ID_RIGHT_WRIST = 15

# 座標履歴を保持するための変数
history_length = 16
point_history_RW = deque(maxlen=history_length)

while video_capture.isOpened():
    # カメラ画像取得
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    if ret is False:
        break

    # 鏡映しになるよう反転
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)

    # MediaPipeで扱う画像は、OpenCVのBGRの並びではなくRGBのため変換
    rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # 画像をリードオンリーにしてHands検出処理実施
    rgb_image.flags.writeable = False
    pose_results = pose.process(rgb_image)
    rgb_image.flags.writeable = True

    # 有効なランドマークが検出された場合、ランドマークを描画
    if pose_results.pose_landmarks.landmark:
        for pose_landmarks in pose_results.pose_landmarks.landmark:
            mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(frame,
                                      pose_results.pose_landmarks,
                                      mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)

            # ランドマーク座標の計算
            landmark_list = calc_landmark_list(rgb_image, pose_results.pose_landmarks)

            # 座標を履歴に追加
            point_history_RW.append(landmark_list[ID_RIGHT_WRIST])


    # ディスプレイ表示
    frame = draw_point_history(frame, point_history_RW)
    cv2.imshow('chapter02', frame)

    # キー入力(ESC:プログラム終了)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:  # ESC
        break

# リソースの解放
video_capture.release()
pose.close()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: ソースコードを変えた内容について、何のために何をさせようとして変えたのか、どういう結果やデータが得られるはずかといったことを、全部をひとまとめに動かした最終結果では無く、変更箇所のそれぞれの箇所でどうなっているかを調べて追記してみてはどうでしょう？ あと処理対象の動画が何であるかを示さないと他の人が動作させて調査・検証することは出来ないと思われます。しかも紹介記事は何かのコースの一部のようなので、オリジナルの動作や結果は登録して受講(有料？)しないと見ることも出来なさそうです。

Comment: リンク先サイトにはコメント欄もあるようなので、レシピの作者に直接質問することも検討してください。

Comment: リンク先に質問することも含めて、一度質問を整理して出直します。